# PHP Access Object properties in the Array

Tags: php, arrays, object, properties

In the array, `Students` objects are stored.

```
class Student {

    //Class definition goes in here.
    private $_name = "";
    private $_student# = 0;
    private $_mojor= ""
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G1ku1.png)

and I want to print out the objects properties in the array using `foreach` and print out in the html table.

```
$counter =0;   

foreach($school->Student as $students) {
 for($x=0;$x<9;$x++) {
 echo'<TR>';
 for ($y=0; $y<2;$y++) {
 echo '<TD>'.$students[$counter].'</TD>';
 }
 $counter++;
 }
}
```

but I have a error like this:

> Trying to get property 'students' of non-object.

How can I get the properties on the object using a `foreach`?

Comment: I mean, the error message is pretty clear.  `$school` is not an object.  You should `var_dump($school);` to see what it actually is.

Comment: Yes, when I used var_dump($school), result like this.
 array(size =10) 
 0 => Object(students)[1]
 private '_name'='aaaa'
 private '_student#"=1111
 private 'major'= math
 ...

 10=>
 private '_name'='zzzzz'
 private '_student#"=9999
 private 'major'= computer.

How can I get does properties?

Comment: Please edit your question to show how $school is declared.

Comment: If `$school` is an array, then that's what you want to loop over instead of `$school->Student`